# Unable to connect to selenium grid node

Tags: java, selenium-grid, selenium3

I am trying to connect to a no on a Linux machine with the RemoteWebDriver, but have been unsuccessful. This is the code:

```
public WebDriver googlechrome(){ /*Method to start Google Chrome.*/

    WebDriver driver = null;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); /*ChromeOptions is for firing Chrome with additional settings.*/
    options.addArguments("--allow-file-access-from-files"); /*Allow Chrome to access files*/
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+System.getProperty("user.dir")+pathChrome);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
    try { //            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9515"), capabilities);
         driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://jenkins.bgr.ionidea.com:4444/grid/console"),capabilities);
         Chatterbox.chatterinfo("Connected to Chromedriver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Chatterbox.chattererror("Could not connect to Chromedriver. Here is the stacktrace:", e); //           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return driver;
}
```

When I run this code on the local machine, it works fine. However, when I try to run it via Grid, the following error is encountered.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote
>   response: Grid Console.busy {
>   opacity : 0.4;filter: alpha(opacity=40);}
>
> ## Selenium
>
> ### Grid Console
>   v.3.1.0
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2'>HelpDefaultRemoteProxy (version : 3.4.0)id : http://proxyhost:port, OS : LINUX
>
>   Browsers
>   Configuration
>
> WebDriver
>
> v:
>
> v:
>
> browserTimeout: 0
>
> debug:
>   false
>
> help: false
>
> port: 5555
>
> role:
>   node
>
> timeout: 1800
>
> cleanUpCycle: 5000
>
> host:
>   10.91.3.204
>
> maxSession: 5
>
> capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5,
>   platform=LINUX}]
>
> capabilities: Capabilities
>   [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5,
>   platform=LINUX}]
>
> downPollingLimit: 2
>
> hub:
>   http://jenkins host:jenkins port
>
> id:
>   http://node ip:node port
>
> hubHost:
>   jenkins.bgr.ionidea.com
>
> hubPort: 4444
>
> nodePolling:
>   5000
>
> nodeStatusCheckTimeout: 5000
>
> proxy:
>   org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
>
> register:
>   true
>
> registerCycle: 5000
>
> remoteHost:
>   http://node ip:node port
>
> unregisterIfStillDownAfter:
>   60000
>
> view
>   config Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision:
>   'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
>   'Brindalas-MacBook-Air-2.local', ip: '10.91.17.123', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:353)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
>     at core.drivers.Browsers.googlechrome(Browsers.java:45)     at
>   core.drivers.Selenium.startBrowser(Selenium.java:18)  at
>   tryFireBrowser.fireBrowser(tryFireBrowser.java:13)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

The first line of the exception says that it is unable to parse something, but I can't understand what?

Am I missing something? I am doing grid setup for the first time.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the node URL from your browser?

Comment: yes I am able to connect to the node url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the below line

`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://jenkins.bgr.ionidea.com:4444/grid/console"),capabilities);`

You are connecting to the Console servlet instead of connecting to the servlet that's responsible for honoring new sessions.

Please change the above line to

`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://jenkins.bgr.ionidea.com:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);`

and try again. You should be fine.